# How to add a sum of a column where the id is matching to another column in SQL

Tags: postgresql

My table has columns called id, totalsales, and p_sales. p_sales is an empty column that I added and I want to fill in this column with the sum of totalsales where the id is matching.

For example, if the first row has an id of 2, I want the p_sales to be filled with the sum of all totalsales with the id of 2. In the next row, if the id is 6 I want the p_sales to be filled with the sum of all totalsales with an id of 6 and so on so forth.

How do I achieve this using SQL?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html with a `join`

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql Server?

Comment: Can you put together a simple SQL Fiddle with this layout? Or at least add your schema information for the two tables you're trying to run this on? It'd also be good if you could show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I believe its Sql Server.

Comment: @hugmungus the table is really small just like I described it and its just one single table. I've tried using update statements but it's not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, only change table1 and table2 with the name of the tables you need

```
 update dodge t set p_sales = (select sum(t2.totalsales) 
from dodge t2 where t2.p_id = t.p_id) ;
```

Comment: This ran but I'm trying to add up the totals from the same table so it gives me the sum of the whole table and not the individual rows with the same id

Comment: copy here the query you're running

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to databases so I dont know exactly what you mean by querry but this is the command I just ran: update dodge set p_sales = (select sum(totalsales) from dodge t2 where t2.p_id = p_id)

Comment: I've eddited my answers, and now its working like you want. Try it.

Comment: I'm getting this error that says: ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist
LINE 1: update t set p_sales = (select sum(t2.totalsales) from dodge...
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: relation "t" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 8

Comment: Really confused on why it's not letting me use "t" to refer to the table. I'm doing this in postgres if that makes any difference

Comment: Start with that, in postgress is diferente than sql server. I haver eddited again. Try